# Logging in a custom Airflow operator

Tags: airflow

I created my own custom operator and I'm doing `logger.info()`, `self.log.info()`, and `print()` and I don't see where these are logged. If I look in `http://localhost:8080/log/list/...` I don't see anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Browse -> Logs (or `http://localhost:8080/log/list/...` ) is an event log. It's not a task log.

`self.log.info()` should work.

It's shown in the task instance log.
Graph View -> click on a task -> click on View Log it will direct you to this Log tab:

[image]

You can also find it with:

```
http://localhost:8080/log?task_id=YOUR_TASK_ID&dag_id=YOUR_DAG_ID&execution_date=EXECUTION_DATE
```